# Android custom list view get adapter

Tags: android, listadapter

hi guys i have been searching for way to get the details of the custom listview. For example i have listview in which a custom view containing a checkbox will be embeded. All that i need to do is to find the state of the checkbox on click of an button. Also need to know how to use the getAdapter method in this case..

Thanks in Advance..

Edit #1

```
class MyEthnicityAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context rContext;
    private LayoutInflater rInflater;
    View view;
    public MyEthnicityAdapter(Context c) {

        rInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);

        rContext = c;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        /* return Library.s.size(); */
        return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ethnicity).length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        // return null;
        System.out.println("My view l;st size is===> " + viewList.size());
        //return viewList.get(position);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        convertView = rInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_multi_select, null);
        EthinicityDataClass mydat = new EthinicityDataClass();

        mydat.ethinicitycheck = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ethnicity_check);

        mydat.ethinicitycheck.setText(getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.ethnicity)[position]);


        view=convertView;
        return convertView;
    }

    class EthinicityDataClass {

        CheckBox ethinicitycheck;
    }

}
```

and i set the adapter like this. `ethnicityListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ethnicityListview);
        ethnicityListview.setAdapter(new MyEthnicityAdapter(this));`

Answer (score 0):

if you do:

```
ethnicityListview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

you can use the

```
ethnicityListview.isItemChecked(position);
```

to get the checked-status of the specified item inside the getView method and react to the value there (check the item if checked, uncheck it if unchecked).